# The meaning of "through your benches coming alongside"

Tags: meaning

> 'Luck of the Gods,' he said. 'Five--four--years ago I might have been
>   waiting for you anywhere in the Long Puddle with fifty River men--and
>   no moon.' Baeticus lifted a moist eye to the slip-hooks on his
>   yardarm, that could hoist and drop weights at a sign. 'You might have
>   had a pig or two of ballast **through your benches coming alongside**,' he
>   said dreamily. 'And where would my overhead-nettings have been?' the
>   other chuckled. 'Blazing--at fifty yards. What are firearrows for?'
>   'To fizzle and stink on my wet sea-weed blindages.

I do not understand the meaning of "send round my kit."
I am glad if some one would  kindly teach me.

This is from "The Manner of Men" by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/LimitsRenewals/mannermen.html

I do not understand the meaning of
 through your benches coming alongside,

I am glad if some one kindly teach me.

Comment: "send round my kit" is not included in your example

Answer (score 1):

A "pig of ballast" was a piece of iron or lead weighing a hundred pounds or more; many of these were carried in the lower part of a ship's hull as ballast to improve her stability.

Baeticus uses these pigs as an offensive weapon: he hoists them up to the yardarm and as he **comes alongside** an opposing vessel swings them over her and drops them from a considerable height hoping to smash a hole **through the benches**, deck, and the hull itself.

Comment: StoneyB, thank you so much for your answer!!! Your teaching is always a great help for me!  Again, I appreciate your kind support.

Comment: @HiroshiInagaki I'm always excited when students read Kipling!